# Badges earned and privileges unlocked in the profile page shows in a weird manner

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

Why am I seeing badges earned and privileges unlocked like this in the profile page? I can see this issue in several Stack Exchange sites.

> [image: SCREENSHOT]

The problems in the above screenshot are:

1. "*You earned a new privilege*" should be above the green checkmark in the first box.
2. "*Edit community wikis*" (or whatever privilege was unlocked) should be beside the green checkmark in the first box and not hidden beside the <kbd>Track the next one ></kbd> button in the first box.
3. "*Congratulations!*" should be above the green checkmark in the second box.
4. The earned badge should be beside the green checkmark and not hidden behind the second box.
5. "*Thanks to your efforts*" text is missing in both the boxes.

Here is an image showing these problems:

> [image: SCREENSHOT]

It should look something like this:

> [image: SCREENSHOT]

I'm using Firefox 40.0.3 on Linux.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but could you more clearly show what's wrong? Since I can't find anything wrong with mine. (Rule #2: Never forget freehands)

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I'll update the image soon... Look at the image carefully and you'll find what's wrong. Basically, "Edit community wikis" is floating left to the blue "Track the next one >" button and the badge is hidden behind the box having "Track the next one" and "Let up pick >"

Comment: And I just found [this](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2739/you-earned-a-new-privilege-is-misaligned) now. Seems to be the same issue.

Comment: Hmm. Can't reproduce in chrome 45.0.2454.84 in android.

Comment: Now, I cannot reproduce this with Firefox 40.0.3 on linux either. Seems to be fixed.

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me last week (on one of the foreign Stack Overflow sites) and today on Mi Yodeya. The issue occurs in multiple browsers (I tested Safari and Firefox on macOS, and Chrome on Windows). The problem seems to be the right margin of the checkmark icon. Normally, it is 14 pixels:

[image: screenshot of current situation]

When I change it to 5 pixels, it looks a lot better:

[image]

---

EDIT: after comparing some other sites, it seems to depend more on the width of the 'You earned a new privilege box'. On Beta sites, e.g. Politics, the width of the box is less than 200 pixels, and it fits next to the checkmark icon:

[image]

On Judaism, the font causes the box to be wider:

[image]

A `max-width` CSS rule solves this issue as well (but it causes the message to be wrapped):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This just [happened to me too over on Ask Different](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2908/3994). I suggest the [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) be dropped from this because it seems to be an ongoing problem rather than one that should be considered tied off.

Comment: I have already raised a custom mod flag asking *exactly* that, but it is pending since November 19th... Still, thanks for the bump. I guess the [status-norepro] was assigned because it's only reproducible on specific sites.

Comment: @Glorfindel custom flags on MSE are sad joke, I stopped flagging long ago (except for rare cases when I can't resist, but I stopped hoping it will ever be handled), it's just pointless. That said, somehow Shog did remove the tag, probably he saw this question by chance.