# Wrong formatting in the profile page

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, badge-progress

This is what I see when viewing [my profile on Mathematics.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/4876/porton):

> [image]

There is apparently some text under "Track the next one / Let us pick". This text is not visible (or rather is partially visible).

This is a bug.

Comment: this same bug shows in a number of sites.

Comment: [It was already reported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265866/badges-earned-and-privileges-unlocked-in-the-profile-page-shows-in-a-weird-manne?lq=1), but since that other one is marked [tag:status-norepro] prefer not to close as dupe just yet.

Comment: @m0sa aren't you in SOinSD? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard [I am](https://twitter.com/SuperDalgas/status/654380350693576705)

Comment: @m0sa cheers, you look very vital! Can you also fix bugs while there? ;)