# What to do about old questions with obvious need for different moderator tags?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, moderator-tags

I just noticed [this question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328645/6388243) on Meta Stack Overflow. It's obvious that it should be tagged [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) and not [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned), as the feature has shipped as of a few months ago.

The only problem is, the last activity was 4 months ago, and I'm not a moderator<sup>[[*citation needed*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citation_(album))]</sup> so I can't make the change myself.

I see a few different possible approaches:

- Apply a tangential edit to the post to bump it
- Raise a custom flag on the post explaining that it should be retagged
- Ping a ♦ moderator or community manager in chat with a link to the post

What is the best way of proceeding in cases like this? Are there other things I could do that I'm missing?

<sup><sup><sup><sub><sub><sub>Awaiting retag via Meta-effect in 3, 2, 1…</sub></sub></sub></sup></sup></sup>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should flag for moderator attention, as they are the only people who can do something about it. This is a perfect use case for a custom moderator flag, as long as you clearly explain *what* needs to be done and *why*.

I'd reserve pinging them for *urgent* issues, and even then, [flag first, ping later](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/34698680#34698680).

Comment: Kinda thought so

Comment: Still, it can take [a long time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265866/badges-earned-and-privileges-unlocked-in-the-profile-page-shows-in-a-weird-manne#comment934873_288035) for them to react.

Comment: We don't always apply the tag because we can't always verify ourselves that it's actually completed without putting in quite a bit of effort. Even as staff, we still don't always know and might have to go bug a bunch of devs to figure out whether or not they remember doing it. A lot of these flags sit around because nobody really knows (they make up a majority of the flag queue here on Meta SE). Unless it's a fairly straight-forward change that can just be seen on a page, yes, it's likely to sit there for a while, and pinging us about it won't actually change anything.