# Privilege Text Messed Up

Tags: bug, design, privileges

[image: Picture 1]

The picture is pretty self-explanatory of the problem: There is some hard-to-see text in the bottom bar for some reason.

I'm not sure what exactly is happening or what should be happening here, but here are two possibilities:

1. The text is supposed to be white and positioned in the middle of the area instead of hugging the bottom.
2. The text is not supposed to be showing overtop of the section, if it is usually not supposed to be visible at this stage.

I have only seen this on one site so far, Mi Yodeya, since I just created an account there, but I suspect this is an issue for multiple sites.

---

I tried on Islam, and there seems to be no issue there:

[image: Picture 2]

So it seems like the positioning of the elements is being messed up in the Mi Yodeya (and possibly other sites) case.

Comment: Well, this is a duplicate of [Badges earned and privileges unlocked in the profile page shows in a weird manner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/265866/307988)... but that was apparently already fixed